# Upload data to server in queue

Tags: android, priority-queue, task-queue

I am creating application in which user will enter bunch of data that can be images, audio, video etc. from android application.

If internet is not available then, the data is inserted in queue (database in my case). And whenever internet is available then from queue one single bunch of data is taken and it is uploaded to server and the uploaded data is removed from queue.

When first bunch of data is completed then, second bunch of data is taken from queue to upload to server.

I have used tape library of square http://square.github.io/tape/

The problem is whenever the data is taken from queue and after finishing upload operation, tape library return call back to queue and next bunch of data is taken to do upload operation.

But, if the call back is not returned then the process of uploading can be stopped.

Can anyone have alternative for tape library?

What are the disadvantages of using tape library?

Comment: you can check there sample application in github [here](https://github.com/square/tape/tree/master/tape-sample) especially [ImageUploadTask](https://github.com/square/tape/blob/master/tape-sample/src/main/java/com/squareup/tape/sample/ImageUploadTask.java) it has implementation for failure() in callback.